# Search by alias without showing the alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of categories and a table of items.

Each item has latitude and longitude to allow me to search by distance.

What I want to do is show each category and how many items are in that category, within a distance chosen.

E.g. Show all TVs in Electronics category within 1 mile of my own latitude and longitude.

Here's what I'm trying but I cannot have two columns within an alias, obviously, and am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

[Here is a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22a7/42)

Here's the query:

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT count(*),( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.412470) ) 
+ sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM items 
WHERE category = category_id group by item_id
HAVING distance < 1  ) AS howmanyCat,
( SELECT name FROM categories WHERE category_id = c.parent ) AS parname 
FROM categories c ORDER BY category_id, parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start with the distance calculation for each item, then join in the category information and aggregate and filter

```
select c.*, count(i.item_id) as numitems
from category c left outer join
     (SELECT i.*, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.412470) ) + sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
                   * sin( radians( latitude ) ) )
                  ) AS distance 
      FROM items i
     ) i
     on c.category_id = i.category_id and distance < 1
group by category_id;
```

Comment: Many thanks!! Can this be modified to show ALL categories? Even it if there is 0 items in them? The reason is for formatting as the parent cats are also in the categories table

Comment: Yes, I moved the `where` condition to the `on`.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly... cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
SELECT categories.name, count(items.item_id) as cnt
FROM items 
JOIN categories 
ON categories.category_id=items.category
WHERE  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) 
* cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.412470) ) 
+ sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) < 1
GROUP BY categories.category_id;
```

this gives:

Tvs | 1

Answer (score 1):

You can put the expression for computing the distance inside a nested `SELECT`, and then join the results to the `categories` table, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), cc.name FROM (
    SELECT
      i.item_id
    , c.category_id
    , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(52.993252) ) 
    * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
    * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-0.412470) ) 
    + sin( radians(52.993252) ) 
    * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM items i
    JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = i.category
) raw 
JOIN categories cc ON raw.category_id = cc.category_id AND raw.distance < 1
GROUP BY cc.name
```

The nested query pairs up items and categories, and adds the calculated distance column. The outer query then filters the rows by distance, and groups them by category to produce the desired output:

```
COUNT(*)    NAME
--------    ----
1           TVs
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22a7/63)